# PHP JSON Options - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, bitmask

In order to provide the second parameter for the PHP function json_encode "options" I use a predefined variable

```
public $jsonParameters = JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE;
```

and call it later with

```
json_encode($result, $this->jsonParameters);
```

This worked all the time but now on one customer server it leads to the following error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ',' or ';' in
```

Is this not a correct way to use the pipe character? But how did it work everywhere else?

Comment: My first impression is, that you use the bitwise OR operator correctly.

Comment: Sounds like your customer uses an ancient PHP version, and you need to become aware of version incompatibilities and set some minimum supported version.

Comment: You can use expressions in PHP 5.6 and newer. Probably, customer server has too outdated PHP version (5.3, for example)